# React : my data from a promise in a useEffect is undefined in my component children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem: In my Post.js component, I try to pass the author, the message and the date as props, but they are "undefined" because they are not yet rendered when the component is rendered. This is the Post.js component :

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const { author, date_creation, message } = post;
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post__author_group">
        <Avatar className={"post__avatar"} />
        <div className="post__author_and_date">
          <Author className="post__author" author={author} />
          <Date className="post__date" date={date_creation} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Text message={message} />
      {/* <Media /> */}
      <Interactions />
    </div>
  );
};
```

So I'm trying to use the promises in my parent Posts.js (Posts with a "s") component (await, async) but the data remains undefined in my child component Post.js.

This is my Posts.js component :

```
const Posts = () => {
  const [dataApi, setDataApi] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const toFetch = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/api/post");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setDataApi(data);
    };
    toFetch();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      <Post />
      {dataApi.map((post) => {
        return <Post post={post} key={uuidv4()} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If in Post.js, i comment  // const { author, date_creation, message } = post and set my props with no dynamics data like author={'author'}, date={'date_creation'} and message={'message'},my console.log(data)return this :

```
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2020-11-11T10:11:11.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
1: {id: 2, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2020-11-11T10:11:11.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
2: {id: 3, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2017-06-29T15:54:04.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
3: {id: 4, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2021-09-03T13:50:33.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
4: {id: 5, message: 'Hello World', date_creation: '2021-09-03T13:50:49.000Z', author: 'Vincent'}
5: {id: 38, message: null, date_creation: null, author: 'req.params.author'}
6: {id: 39, message: 'message en dur bla blablabla bla blabla', date_creation: '2021-09-02T10:25:06.000Z', author: 'Auteur en dur'}
7: {id: 40, message: 'message en dur bla blablabla bla blabla', date_creation: '2021-09-02T10:25:06.000Z', author: 'Auteur en dur'}
8: {id: 41, message: 'message en dur bla blablabla bla blabla', date_creation: '2021-09-02T10:25:06.000Z', author: 'Auteur en dur'}
9: {id: 42, message: 'message en dur bla blablabla bla blabla', date_creation: '2021-09-02T10:25:06.000Z', author: 'Auteur en dur'}
10: {id: 43, message: 'message en dur bla blablabla bla blabla', date_creation: '2021-09-02T10:25:06.000Z', author: '[object Object]'}
length: 11
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But if i put dynamic data like my props, i have the error that author is undefined etc.

I don't understand ... Anyone know? Thank you !

Comment: Check the code properly there is one <Post /> without any props. 3rd line in return

Comment: Ok i have remove it and it's work so thanks ! but i don't understantd what is the connection ?

Comment: You are calling Post multiple times. each post has its own instance. so when you call a Post without props this child doesn't have a props inside as well. Please go through React docs

Comment: Ok i understand, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering a `<Post />` with no props, and you should remove that!

Comment: Ok i have remove it and it's work so thanks ! but i don't understantd what is the connection ?